# Compare two DNA-like strings with MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, performance, compare, stored-functions

I'm trying to find a way to compare two DNA-like strings with MySQL, stored functions are no problem. Also the string may be changed, but needs to have the following format: `[code][id]-[value]` like `C1-4`. (- may be changed aswell)

*Example of the string:*

`C1-4,C2-5,C3-9,S5-2,S8-3,L2-4`

If a value not exists in the other string, for example `S3-1` it will score 10 (max value). If the asked string has `C1-4` and the given string has `C1-5` the score has to be `4 - 5 = -1` and if the asked string is `C1-4` and the given string has `C1-2` the score has to be `4 - 2 = 2`.

The reason for a this is that my realtime algorithm is getting slow with 10.000 results. (already optimized with stored functions, indexes, query optimalizations) Because 10.000 x small and quick queries will make a lot. 
And the score has to be calculated before I can order my query and get the right limit.

**Thanks** and if you have any questions let me know by comment.

** EDIT **

I'm thinking that it's also possible to not use a string but a table where the DNA-bits are stored as a 1-n relation table.

`ID | CODE | ID | VALUE`
`----------------------`
`1. | C...    | 2.  | 4....`

Comment: i would use mysql to store my data. not to execute an algorythm

Comment: I understand, but would you load 10.000 sets of data to perform an algorithm to get the top 10 sets? With the idea that the set will still grow (up to 100.000 if we are lucky)

Comment: i would not use mysql to store my data